# How do I conditionally execute bash code based on the comparison of file dates?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for f in $SOMEDIR
    do
        if "$f is newer than some other file"
        then
             "do this"
        else
             "do this"
        fi
    done
fi
```

I know I've seen a nice and easy way to quickly compare file dates and execute if the first file date happens to be newer than the second but I have no clue where to look to find that again.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a file test operator.

Taken from: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

f1 -nt f2
file f1 is newer than f2

f1 -ot f2
file f1 is older than f2

Assuming test and test2 are files.

```
if [[ "test" -nt "test2" ]]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi

if [[ "test" -ot "test2" ]]; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Executed:

```
 $ ./test
 yes
 no
```